# Why does Java let you overwrite variables?

Tags: java

```
public class Example3_1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int number1 = 1;
        int number2;
        number1 = 12;
        number2 = 23;
        System.out.println(number1 + number2);
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain to me why Java lets you overwrite variables as so? The variable `number1` on line 3 and `number1` on line 5 are overwriting each other, someone please explain.

Comment: What do you mean "overwriting eachother"? What is the output you are expecting? This program currently properly outputs `35`.

Comment: You can use the `final` keyword to make so the variable cannot be overwritten.

Comment: "The Variable number1 on line 3 and number1 on line 5 are overwriting each other" - there is only one `number1` variable, not two.

Comment: For java to be turing complete it needs to allow you to overwrite data.

Comment: Notice how numer1 on line 3 equals "1" and number1 on line 3 equals "12" I am not talking about the output i am talking about inside the code.

Comment: This is one of the core concepts of programming in general and suggests that you might want to get an introductory programming book and go through the first couple of chapters. You wont regret doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overwriting the value of variable(variation) is the main idea about variables. This is not the exclusive feature of the java and all of the programming languages support this feature. Without this feature you are unable to implementing the simple problems ever. Indeed your question is about programming not about JAVA!!

In your example the "number1" in two appearances is the same but its value changes.

Comment: I see, Thank you! I'm a actually quite new to programming currently learning java and python, would make sense why i had no clue about this, THANKS!!!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)#Single_assignment - modifiable variables are not necessary, a lot of (pure functional) languages don't have that as a feature and yet are perfectly capable languages.

Comment: Thanks Mat. But I think your comment say about explicit and implicit assignment not about the VARIABLE and its duty.

Comment: My comment is about your assertion that you can't do "the simple problems ever" without mutable variables. That is wrong. Not all language have mutable variables either. That assertion is wrong too

Answer (score 2):

The literal meaning of variable is,

> Variable-not consistent or having a fixed pattern; liable to change.

Why do you think this name is chosen ?

In programming terms, Variable points to the memory location that holds a value. Every time you change the value, it gets updated in the memory location.

`final` is the keyword in java that implements `constants`

```
final int SPEED=300;
```

The variable `SPEED`'s value cannot be changed. This is actually modifying the natural behaviour of variable.

Answer (score 1):

When it's not able to overwrite a `variable` you are talking about a `constant`.

A lot of times you will have to store values, delete values, modify values and if the variables couldn't be overwrited it would be imposible to solve all of these problems.

Answer (score 0):

basically variables represent memory locations where the value is stored. when variables are not overriden then probably you will have to have lots of memory locations(variables) to store every value of yours.. so when you feel a memory location or a variable is no longer needed for you..you can go ahead and re-assign it to something else.